# Do we need a [homework] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-tag

[This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/83353/how-flexibility-of-wing-affects-the-bending-moment-and-root-shear-force) is currently tagged with [homework](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework). I had previously removed this tag from some other questions, but since it keeps reappearing, it is probably best do discuss it here on Meta.

The topic has been mentioned before by ymb1 in [this Meta post](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3998/homework-questions-has-something-changed-perhaps-network-wide):

> On a related note, the tag [homework](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) was created, but I deleted it, as it is an orphan tag, and I don't see what value it adds to the question, whether it's on or off-topic (feel free to discuss this point as well).

But there was no discussion on that particular point. I tend to agree with this, it is a meta tag that adds nothing relevant to the question. **What do you think?**

---

Related:

- [Should we answer exam or test questions?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394/should-we-answer-exam-or-test-questions)
- [Homework questions: has something changed, perhaps network-wide?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3998/homework-questions-has-something-changed-perhaps-network-wide)

Comment: If you've come to a consensus, @Federico, please have a look at [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239189/208518) and others linked therein for next steps — once you get to step 4, please create a separate [meta-tag:feature-request] and [meta-tag:status-review] that one instead :)

Comment: @JNat I understood that this discussion was already covering point one, and point 3 says "If you already posted a meta discussion during Step #1's "burninate" process, you'll have this rationale readily available." so aren't we already at step 4?

Comment: Right, I shoulda looked to make sure the tag clean-up had already been performed... :P I'll retag it, then @Federico ^_^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it is a pointless tag.

Tags are supposed to say what the question is about so that people can decide before opening if they might be able to answer or not.

Highlighting that a question is about "homework" is not informative in this sense: is it about aerodynamics? or about construction? or something else? Well, for all those things we already have a tag, homework is thus superfluous.

I say we don't need it.

And I would propose to block it altogether if it is agreed.

Answer (score 2):

I've deleted the tag from the question it appeared on, which should cause it to be removed from the system automatically within the next 24 hours.

In most cases, this is all that is necessary. We generally only block tags when they keep coming back and are causing issues on the site. In general, our recommendation is to delete all instances of the bad tag and wait for the tag removal script. This would have self-solved after six months as there's a script that removes tags that are only used on a single question (as was the case here) but I've sped up the process (and any user with the ability to see deleted questions could have, too) by deleting the tag.

Please let me know if there are any questions or concerns.